# Uncaught error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm really new to react, im trying to build an app in that library, however i keep running into this error and i don't know what it does nor how to resolve it.
I'm just trying to pass data from a parent component to a child component, previously i was trying to do that from a fetch and from an array but now it's just basic props and still i get this error.

the parent component

```
import axios, * as others from 'axios';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Cerd from "./Cerd";
import movieArray from "./MovieArray";


export function UseFetch(message){

   let number =  movieArray.length;
   console.log(number);
   let image = movieArray[0].image;
   let text = movieArray[0].title;
   let actors = movieArray[0].actors;
   const toStringer = text.toString();
console.log(toStringer);

    return(
        <div className="row-wrapper">
            <Row>    
                <Cerd title="ciao"/>
            </Row>
        </div>
        )
        
    }
```

the child component:

```
mport Card from 'react-bootstrap/card';
    
export default function Cerd(title){
    console.log(title);

    
    return(
        <div>{title}</div>
    )
    
}
```

Here's the error:

[image: 1]

I already tried to change computer and search for solutions online but nothing changes, I0m not passing an array or an object in the props as it is just a simple string. This is a killer error because it's not the first time that happens to me and i still haven't found what to do when it happens... can somebody help?

EDIT: I was asked to post the movieArray component, so here it is:

```
const movieArray = [{
title: "ciao",
actors: "celine dion",
image: "./public/logo192.png"
```

},{
title: "ciao",
actors: "celine dion",
image: "./public/logo192.png"
},{
title: "ciao",
actors: "celine dion",
image: "./public/logo192.png"
}]

export default movieArray;

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: `UseFetch({message}){` `function Cerd({title})`

Answer (score 1):

In react component props passing, you cannot take it like taking from function.
You defined "title" in props of component, but you cannot take it as a variable. You have to take it as shorthand.

```js
// your code;
export default function Cerd(title){

// must be;
                               \/
export default function Cerd({title}){
```

Try ({title}) instead of (title).

Comment: Thank u so much, it logs undefined when i try to log the prop. I would like for it to console the value i'm trying to pass in the parent component, how can i do that? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Is movieArray a react component? What are u exporting from movieArray component? Can u edit ur question and show to us?

Comment: movieArray it's just an array of objects and i'm exporting the array.